# IntegrityError for AutoField after a bulk_create()

Tags: python, django, postgresql

after doing a `bulk_create`, I'm trying to add some elements to my table but I got an IntegrityError as the sequence still starts with 1 when using `save()`

Is there any way to update the sequence within Django after the bulk_create ? Or should I generate the id myself using a max filter ?

I'm using a postgre database.

Here is a sample of my code:
`elements` is a list of `Identifiants` objects (I'm trying to import the list on a "dump" database first to be sure everything is fine)

```
try:
    Identifiants.objects.using('import-check').all().delete()
    Identifiants.objects.using('import-check').bulk_create(elements)
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    return False
else:
    Identifiants.objects.all().delete()
    Identifiants.objects.bulk_create(elements)
    return True
```

And here's the model

```
class Identifiants(models.Model):
    taxon = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    noms = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    fiche = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sms = models.NullBooleanField()
```

I let Django create the pk itself

And the view related for further insertions :

```
    elif req.method == 'POST' and req.POST['action'] == "add":
        id_form = AddFormId(req.POST)
        nom_form = AddFormNom(req.POST)
        search_form = LightSearchForm(req.POST)
        if id_form.is_valid() and nom_form.is_valid():
            inst = id_form.save(commit = False)
            num_fiche = Identifiants.objects.all().aggregate(Max('fiche'))['fiche__max']
            num_fiche += 1
            inst.fiche = num_fiche
            inst.save()
            values = nom_form.save(commit = False)
            values.taxon = inst
            values.codesyno = 0
            values.save()
            return redirect(reverse(details, kwargs = {'id_item' : values.id}))
```

I got the issue with multiple tables. I always add elements with a form.

Comment: Please show relevant code, your model and how you are using `bulk_create`. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my question with the code !

Comment: And how you are adding more elements after `bulk_create`?

Comment: Edited ! I just call `save` on a ModelForm instance after validation